# Слайды в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Изучаю `bootstrap`. Хочу сделать переключающиеся слайды на странице. Не понимаю почему, но у меня отображается только первая картинка и нет значка перехода влево или вправо. Что я делаю не так ?

```
        <!-- Слайдер -->
        <dev id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <!-- Активный индикатор-->
                <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <!-- Неактивные индикаторы -->
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Слайды -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/universe.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/universe.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/universe.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!-- Слайдер -->
<dev
```

Нет такого тега `dev`!

Правильно - `<div>` и все заработает:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<div class="container">
  <!-- Слайдер -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <!-- Активный индикатор-->
                <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <!-- Неактивные индикаторы -->
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Слайды -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
                        <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Да, заработало. Но у меня почему-то нет круглых кнопок переключения на нужный слайд внизу как у вас. Не подскажите в чем может быть дело ?

Comment: я скопировала Ваш код и только первый тег исправила - все работает как видите. Возможно какие-то стили перекрывают. Для слайдера дополнительно что-то прописывали.

Comment: Леночка , я тут с месяц назад писал страничку вообще придумал тегов миллион , работало и css тоже применялся но мину только был в том что валидатор не то что бы ругался а матюкался

Comment: В данном случае, лично у меня, не работало именно из-за тега)